# Number of solutions of ODE system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve the following problem:

How many solutions $(x(t), y(t))$ with initial condition $x(1)=1$ has the system $$\dot x=1+xy, \dot y=t-y^2:$$
zero, one or infinity?

Of course I am not particularly interested in the answer, but in proof and approach to the problem.

Unfortunately I do not know how to approach this problem and post my attempt, but I will be very grateful for your hints and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no initial value for $y$ and every initial value problem has a local solution, there is as much variation as there is in values for $y(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you a bit elaborate where you used this particular form of the system? I think that your argument is not applicable to any system, right (because there are systems with no or single solutions)?

Comment: Any explicit ODE system with continuous right side has local solutions for any tuple of initial values, this is the existence theorem of Peano.